# What does this c++ statement check? (Box2d)

Tags: c++, box2d

```
if ((catA & maskB) != 0 && (catB & maskA) != 0)
```

It is in [Box2d's manual: 6.2](http://box2d.org/manual.html#_Toc258082972), and is used to check if two objects should collide (after filtering)

Comment: ? seems like you answered the question yourself :)

Comment: I want to know what the code does to decide on if they should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

catA is a bit field of collision categories for object A
maskA is a bit field of categories that object A can collide with.

For example:

```
catA  = 100010000010010 // Object A is in 4 collision categories
maskA = 001010000000000 // Object A can collide with too different categories

catB  = 000010001000001 // Object B is in 3 collision categories
maskB = 100000000000000 // Object B can only collide with the category represented by the highest bit
```

catA & maskB means the bits that are 1 in both catA and maskB, so `1000000000000000`. It's not 0, because Object B can collide with objects in the highest bit, and object A has that bit set.

catB & maskA means the bits that are 1 in both catB and maskA, so `0000100000000000`. It's also not zero since Object A can collide with objects in the 5th highest bit category, and Object B is in that category.

So the two objects can collide.

Answer (score 2):

It checks that catA has at least one common '1' bit with maskB, and catB has at least one common '1' bit with maskA.

For example, if catA is 3 (binary 00000011) and maskB is 10101010), then (catA & maskB) != 0 is true because catA & maskB is 00000010.

This is called masking, which means only keeping bits of interest.

You frequently have this kind of construct :

```
#define READ 1
#define WRITE 2
#define READWRITE (READ|WRITE)
#define DIRECTORY 4

int i=getFileInfo("myfile");
if(i & READWRITE)puts("you can read or write in myfile"); 
if(i & DIRECTORY)puts("myfile is a directory");
```

BTW, "i & DIRECTORY" means the same as "(i & DIRECTORY) != 0"

Answer (score 0):

the symbol `&` is the bitwise AND operator. Therefore, the statement

```
(catA & maskB) != 0
```

checks to see if any bits overlap in both of those items. It looks at if it checks A against B first, then B against A.

Answer (score 0):

I know many C/C++ programmers love terseness but I find this type of code can be made much more readable by moving this test into a function (you can inline it if you want). They could also have gotten rid of the comment by moving the code to a well named method.

```
if (FixturesCanCollide() )
{
}
```

You can actually throw away the comparison to !=0 (although you might prefer it for clarity, either way it probably compiles down to the same code.

```
inline bool FixturesCanCollide()
{   
   return  (catA & maskB) && (catB & maskA);
}
```